# Passing a method that return a bool value into a while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, do-while

C# question:

I have a method A(string) that returns a true or false.

I am running a while loop running until method(string) returns true.

The problem is I have these while loops all over the place.

How can I have a single while loop method and pass in the method(string) from anywhere?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Please don't describe your code, *show* it in the form or a [mre] (with emphasis on the minimal part). Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: ok thanks will keep that in mind for future posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Func<string, bool>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-6.0) as Parameter, please check following code:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        ManyWhiles1(A);
        ManyWhiles2(A);
    }

    private static bool A(string input)
    {
        return (input == "abc");
    }

    private static void ManyWhiles1(Func<string, bool> a)
    {
        string input = "abc";
        while (a(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working ...");
        }

        while (a(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working ...");
        }
    }

    private static void ManyWhiles2(Func<string, bool> a)
    {
        string input = "abc";
        while (a(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working ...");
        }

        while (a(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working ...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers without any kind of explanation about how it solves the problem being asked about, and what the problem actually was, are highly discouraged as they tend to lead to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Please take some time to refresh [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).